# Modify a variable by using a copy of it inside a table in Lua

Tags: lua

I want (in Lua) to modify a variable by a copy af this variable inserted inside a table like this :

```
t = {}
v = 1
t.variable = v
t.variable = t.variable + 1
print(v)
-- i want it to print 2 but it prints 1
```

I want to modify v by modifying t.variable but of course it don't work. Is there any way to do what i want to do ?

Comment: The thing you're trying to do here is not allowed by the rules of the language, other than through some ugly and probably bad-idea metatable stuff. So what is it you *want to do with it*? What are you trying to accomplish, that you feel requires the language working in this way? ([edit] your question to include that information.)

Comment: what I exactly for a 2D video game, have function to move an object from a point a to point b in a given time.

Comment: @SpaceChaton so basically `zombie.x = zombie.x + 1` - then what is `v`, can you just use `zombie.x` instead of using `v`?

Comment: @user253751 v is the zombie table in a big table of all zombies currently moving

Comment: If v is "the zombie table", how could you ever add 1 to it?

Comment: by using zombie.x

Comment: @SpaceChaton So v is a table? Try doing your experiment with a table. I think it will work how you expect. When you do `a = b` and a is a table then it doesn't copy the table - just the reference to the table - both a and b hold references to the same table

Comment: so if you do for example `local a,b` and `a={}` and `b=a` and `b.x = 50` and `print(a.x)` it prints 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a pointer or a reference. They don't really exist in Lua, but we can replicate their functionality using tables. It may look ugly to some though.

```lua
t = {}
v = {value = 1}
t.variable = v
t.variable.value = t.variable.value + 1
print(v.value)
```

This works because tables never get copied, we always get a reference to them.

Comment: I am little casual programmer so I dont "talk with computers" and I don't understand what an ugly code mean, can you tell me ?

Comment: @SpaceChaton Ugly code depends on the programmer. I personally find continuously indexing some table difficult to understand when what the table and the indexed value represent is similar. Looking at `v` is much easier to understand than `v.value` in my opinion.

Comment: I'd say a less ugly approach to modify a variable would be to (1) use an upvalue or (2) `return` the changed value, then do `var = change(var)` when calling it.